# Determine all possible solutions of the congruence $5x \equiv 7 \pmod {15}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I wonder if there is a good method for these types of problems when the integer on the left side isn't inversable.

Comment: Suppose $5x=7+15n$.  for integers $x,n$.  Deduce that $5$ divides $7$.

Comment: 5x = 7 + 15k; 5|15k so 5|7.  No solutions.

Comment: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Solution_of_Linear_Congruence#Theorem

Answer (score 0):

Since $5x ≡ 7 (mod 15)\Leftrightarrow 5x=5(3k+1)+2$ and $5\not|\;2$, there is no solution.

Answer (score 0):

"Brute Strength" works (and doesn't require all that much "strength"). 5(1)= 5, 5(2)= 10, 5(3)= 15= 0, 5(4)= 20= 5, 5(6)= 30= 0, 5(7)= 35= 5, 5(8)= 40= 10, 5(9)= 45= 0, 5(10)= 50= 5, 5(11)= 55= 10, 5(12)= 60= 0, 5(13)= 65= 5, 5(14)= 70= 10. (All mod 15, of course.).  5 times anything is 0, 5, or 10 (mod 15).

There is **no** value of x that "5x= 7 mod 15".